# How to assume/steal another process's windows as my own?

Tags: windows-7, process, taskbar

I'd like to show another app's windows under my app's taskbar button. It's a background app that reports another process's windows as my app's own. Is there any universal way to do this, e.g. each "new" window, alert glow, progressmeter, and other taskbar features, show under my own app's button?

For example, [Winfox runs under its own process and steals Firefox's windows](http://i46.tinypic.com/eq5coh.png). It also adds features, but that's irrelevant -- I just want to support another app's existing taskbar features under my own app's button -- multiple windows, progressmeter, alert flashing, error flashing, mini-icons, etc. Is there a near-universal way to steal an app, or is it largely app-specific? Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't sound like something I'd like running on my computer.  Can't you update your app to provide this functionality?

Comment: I want to make a jumplist utility -- the idea is that I feed my app, say, foobar2000.exe or any non-Win7 app, and I add jumplists to my app. My app then runs commands on foobar2000. Perhaps that makes it clear why I want my app to show another process's windows?

Jumplists are sickly useful for tablet pcs, but the thing is most apps are slow to adopt it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [SetParent()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633541(VS.85).aspx) to take ownership of a window, but I'm not sure how much this will help you in your attempt to add taskbar features to the legacy app.

Comment: I thought this was right, but spoke too soon :) It looks like this just allows child windows to be assigned a different parent, but my app doesn't have a window. It's a "background" app that simply reports another process's windows as its own, so I suppose this might not help me...